# How to download rpm file from google artifact registry's yum repository using API call?

Tags: rpm, yum, google-artifact-registry

How to download rpm file from google artifact registry's yum repository using API call?

I tried using the API request format https://-yum.pkg.dev/projects///Packages/ since a similar format is used by yum to download packages from repositories.
But I get a 404 (Requested entity was not found.)

Answer (score 0):

- To download RPM file from Google Artifact Registry's YUM repository using API call, you have to construct the URL correctly as following:

  ```
  https://<REGION>-yum.pkg.dev/<PROJECT-ID>/<REPOSITORY-ID>/<PACKAGE-NAME>
  ```
- Example URL looks like:

  ```
  https://us-west1-yum.pkg.dev/test-project/test-repo/test-package.rpm
  ```
- Make sure that you have the correct values for region, project id, repository id, package name. You can get those details from the Google Cloud Console or Artifact Registry API.
- If still getting the `404 error (Requested entity was not found)` double check the  existence of `packages`. And also check for `permission` to access the package in the repository. And lastly check for the `region` is correct.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering the question, but I get 404 (Not found) when I try the above mentioned url format. For package name I tried using the format <package_name>.rpm and also tried using the filename which I got after calling the list files api but none of them worked. Can you please clarify from where should I get the <PACKAGE-NAME>.

Comment: The package name in the API request should be the name of the package as it appears in the repository. To retrieve the package name you can you use the following command: `GET https://artifactregistry.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/<REGION>/repositories/<REPOSITORY>/files
`. In response you should see list of files including package names